# Add class when div visible on screen

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code :

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu" id="menu-features">
        <a href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<a id="features"></a>
<div id="div-features">
<!-- SOME CODE HERE -->
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery script :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if $('#div-features').visible(){
            $('#menu-features').addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

now, here's the problem :

I want to add a class to list item, in this case `#menu-features` only when div `#div-features` visible on the screen. once it's not visible then the class will be removed.

but, it seems that jQuery `.addClass` not affecting anything on `#menu-features`.

what did I do wrong here? thank you.

UPDATE : I tried also, but still failed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#div-features').is(':visible')){
        //$('#menu-features').addClass("active");
        alert('Hello, World!!');
    }                               
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :Your `if` condition having error, please follow below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($('#div-features').is(':visible')){
         $('#menu-features').addClass("active");
    }
 });
```

Comment: nope... still didn't work out... I tried to alert some text too but still that IF condition not triggered.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement? have you added jQuery library to your page?

Comment: I think the problem is with my safari browser... I works now... thanks

Comment: bro, I have another issue with your suggestion there... when my website is fully loaded, why the class applied immediately while the div still in the bottom (not visible yet)? any idea what cause it?

Comment: I think your are looking for element when visible on the screen after scrolling. This should be handled in different way, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: Not worked for me, I was used it to do animations but doesn't solve my issue

Comment: @raviramani, how can you say that this is wrong answer when user accepted it. It may happen that your problem is something else which does not fit the given solution. Can you share your code on SO and share the link here

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this on scroll

> waypoint

is opacity 0 to hide the element
then

> animated

shows the element if it is 30% visible on window

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.waypoint').each(function (i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() * 0.3);
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).addClass('animated');
            }
        });
```